# The list of users is not correctly aligned

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

In [this list of users with a badge](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/badges/12/strunk-white?userid=1229), the usernames are not correctly aligned.

[image: screenshot]

The name in the last column is lower than the name in the third column, which is higher than the name in the second column.

Comment: it's because of the mod diamonds, etc

Comment: It must be an heavy diamond. `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem no longer applies as there have been significant styling changes on that page.